# get key in array php and then sort array with the keys?

Tags: php, arrays

if i have a array

```
Array
(
[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => title = title dffgfghfdg
        [1] => 2-title2
        [2] => content = content 2
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => title = title erer
        [1] => 1-title1
        [2] => content = content 1
    )

[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => title = title sdfdf
        [1] => 4-title4
        [2] => content = content 4
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => title = titledfdf df
        [1] => 3-title3
        [2] => content = content 3
    )
)
```

and i will make every [1] to be key. becouse i will sort the array within [1]..?

probably will be

```
Array
(
[2-title2] => Array
    (
        [0] => title = title dffgfghfdg
        [1] => 2-title2
        [2] => content = content 2
    )

[1-title1] => Array
    (
        [0] => title = title erer
        [1] => 1-title1
        [2] => content = content 1
    )

[4-title4] => Array
    (
        [0] => title = title sdfdf
        [1] => 4-title4
        [2] => content = content 4
    )

[3-title3] => Array
    (
        [0] => title = titledfdf df
        [1] => 3-title3
        [2] => content = content 3
    )
)
```

then i will sort with the keys?
thanks

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. Are you asking how to sort the array with the non-integer keys?

Answer (score 3):

Use a foreach() to transform the array, then use ksort().

```
foreach($a as $k => $v) {
   $b[$v[1]] = $v;
}
ksort($b);
```

Something like that.

Answer (score 3):

Use `usort` for it.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

```
function user_cmp( $a, $b )
{
    if( $a[1] == $b[1] ) return 0;
    return ($a[1] < $b[1]) ? -1 : 1;
}

$arr = array( ... );
usort( $arr, 'user_cmp' );
```

Comment: +1, but I would simplify user_cmp to just `return strcmp($a[1], $b[1]);`.